# My light switch trips the breaker when its placed into the box

Tags: electrical, lighting, circuit-breaker

I have a box that contains 3 light switches.  I replaced the old switches with new ones simply for cosmetic reasons.  The old panel worked perfectly fine.  When I install the new switches everything is fine.  However, when I compress them all into the box and make everything nice and tidy, it trips the breaker.  Is something rubbing in there?  Does the proximity have something to do with my problem?

Comment: Is the box metal or plastic?

Comment: Make sure all the terminations are tight, and that any bare ground wires are not near any ungrounded (hot) terminals.

Comment: The screws on the side of a switch are hitting a bare ground wire.  Pull it apart and look close, you'll see arc marks.   I like to wrap electrical tape around the switch or outlet body so it covers those screws.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have skinned a hot wire that is touching the metal box or one of the ground wires. With the power off pull the switches and look for a burned spot. If the wire is still ok not damaged from shorting it can be taped with a quality electrical tape. If the wire is damaged you will want to cut it and pigtail a new piece. This happens even to professionals.